# Getting path from lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have code like this:

```
string PropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
{
    var body = expression.Body as MemberExpression;

    if (body == null)
    {
        body = ((UnaryExpression)expression.Body).Operand as MemberExpression;
    }

    return body.Member.Name;
}
```

I use it in this fashion:

```
Console.WriteLine(PropertyName(() => this.Property));
```

which prints `Property` on screen

Now I would like to change it so:

```
Console.WriteLine(PropertyName(() => this.OtherObject.Property));
```

would give me `OtherObject.Property` instead of just `Property`. Is this even possible?

The purpose is to create bindings to dependency properties from code without hard coding of property names.

I also have a question when does the `body` on line `5` equals to `null`? I copied this code mindlessly and leave it at it was but this condition appears to never be true.

Comment: `((UnaryExpression)expression.Body).Operand as MemberExpression` is for the case of `Expression.Convert` which can occur due to implicit casting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    string PropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
    {
        var body = expression.Body as MemberExpression;

        if (body == null)
        {
            body = ((UnaryExpression)expression.Body).Operand as MemberExpression;
        }

        return string.Join(".", GetPropertyNames(body).Reverse());
    }

    private IEnumerable<string> GetPropertyNames(MemberExpression body)
    {
        while (body != null)
        {
            yield return body.Member.Name;
            var inner = body.Expression;
            switch (inner.NodeType)
            {
                case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:
                    body = inner as MemberExpression;
                    break;
                default:
                    body = null;
                    break;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It reverses the order of calls but apart from that seems to work fine :) Thank you